# unable to solve error in build output in values.xml file

Tags: resources, android-drawable, invalid-characters, valuestack, optional-values

I am trying to solve this error : C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\28a7af075d5af218c19b63a2f54b1523\transformed\core-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml:29:4: Invalid  for given resource value.
the problem showing is in build output. I tried in many ways. how to solve it ?

I tried to solve this error in build output (in andriod studio): C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\28a7af075d5af218c19b63a2f54b1523\transformed\core-1.9.0\res\values\values.xml:29:4: Invalid  for given resource value.
I am expecting with answer to resolve this issue.